# what is the default format of loading multi line data in d3?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js, charts

I am trying to create a multi line chart with d3. I can manipulate my data in any format in the controller and pass it to the graph but not sure what is the default format or best practice that d3 accepts. examples are very different and working with different form of entries with different methods such as:

file readers:

```
 csv()
 tsv()
 col1,col2,col3
 x1,y1,y2,...
 x2,y1,y2,...
```

or array of objects:

```
[
    {key:"col1",value:[[x1,y1],[x2,y2],...]},
    {key:"col2",value:[[x1,y1],[x2,y2],...]},
]
```

or

```
 [ 
 { label: "col1", 
    x: [x1, x2, x3,...], 
    y: [y1, y2, y3,...] }, 
 { label: "col2", 
    x: [x1, x2, x3,...], 
    y: [y1, y2, y3,...] } 
 ] ;
```

and so many other formats...

But basically I am looking for a default format that I can pass multi series of data to d3 with the less amount of data manipulation in chart codes. I want to only pass the prepared data to d3.

Comment: Pass each variable as a point in JSON`[{x: 1; y: 2; group: A}, {x:2; y: 4; group: B}...]`, nest the data with whatever keys (group by), and draw the lines from the nested data object.

Comment: EDIT:  if you work in R (or not) I found this tutorial helpful: https://proquestionasker.github.io/blog/d3Nest/. Good luck!

Comment: @RyanMorton thanks for answer. I am not sure what group does here?! why it si y2 and y4? to give more info, I want to append multi lines in one loop of reading data. not adding each line by looping on dataset for each different Y value.

Comment: Group A follows one line, group B follows another line, but both have x and y values.You could send this data in the JSON format I showed you - the values were arbitrary. Also, look at the tutorial - the lines get drawn in a single loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of answering *"what is the default format of loading multi line data in d3?"*, which is quite vague and clearly opinion based (since there is no *default format*), I'll just explain some basic D3 principles of joining data.

The data method (`selection.data()`) accepts 3 things:

- An array
- A function
- Nothing

So, we'll use an array to store the data for the multiline.

And now comes the important part: the line generator itself uses an array for drawing the paths. According to the API, [d3.line](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#line):

> Generates a line for the given array of data.

Therefore, this is the simplest format for a multiline:

```
[//outer array
    [...],
    [...],
    [...]
    //inner arrays, one for each line
]//closing the outer array
```

Those inner arrays can contain objects or even other arrays (with two values each, one for `x` position and the other for `y` position).

For instance, the inner arrays containing objects:

```
var data = [
    [{x:0, y: 0},{x:50, y: 40},{x:100, y: 100},{x:150, y: 90},{x:200, y: 150}],
    [{x:0, y: 50},{x:50, y: 60},{x:100, y: 100},{x:150, y: 110},{x:200, y: 10}],
    [{x:0, y: 20},{x:50, y: 20},{x:100, y: 140},{x:150, y: 130},{x:200, y: 10}]
];
```

And containing arrays:

```
var data = [
    [[0, 10],[50, 20],[100, 30]],
    [[0, 80],[50, 10],[100, 40]],
    [[0, 50],[50, 120],[100, 90]]
];
```

As this is one of the *simplest* formats it may suit you, since you said: *"I am looking for a default format that I can pass multi series of data to d3 with the less amount of data manipulation"*.

You just need to create an enter selection, like this:

```
var lines = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", lineGenerator)
```

The number of lines (paths) is the number of inner arrays. For each line (path), the respective inner array is passed as the data.

Here is a demo:

```js
var data = [
[{x:0, y: 0},{x:50, y: 40},{x:100, y: 100},{x:150, y: 90},{x:200, y: 150},{x:250, y: 140},{x:300, y: 130}],
[{x:0, y: 120},{x:50, y: 60},{x:100, y: 100},{x:150, y: 110},{x:200, y: 90},{x:250, y: 10},{x:300, y: 30}],
[{x:0, y: 20},{x:50, y: 20},{x:100, y: 140},{x:150, y: 130},{x:200, y: 10},{x:250, y: 70},{x:300, y: 90}]
];
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10)
var lineGenerator = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return d.x
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return d.y
  })

var lines = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", lineGenerator)
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke-width", 3)
  .attr("stroke", function(d, i) {
    return color(i)
  })
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid darkgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

And how people create those nested arrays based on data (for instance, a CSV or a TSV)? That's a different question. The most common way (but not the only one), as suggested [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45601588/what-is-the-default-format-of-loading-multi-line-data-in-d3/45602459#comment78162835_45601588), is using `d3.nest()`.

Comment: Thanks great answer. one question, why do you pass `null` to `svg.selectAll(null)`?

Comment: I wrote a full explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/d3.js/2135/selections/16948/the-role-of-placeholders-in-enter-selections#t=201708102220450184304